# How to parse text from an excel document in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a csv with several accented characters including country names. I'm using a csv reader with a specified encoding and dialect to parse it, but it's not handling the accents well.

```
p = re.compile('(?<=n).*?(?=,)')
with open('/file.csv', 'rt', encoding='cp1252') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, dialect='excel')
    next(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row[0])
        accented_words = p.findall(row[8])[0].strip()
        print(accented_words)
```

`p` is a regex that pulls some accented characters out. It gives me results like 'C™te dÕIvoire'. How can I get past this and preserve the accented characters?

Comment: Are you sure it's `cp1252` encoding? It's likely that this file is actually utf-8, or some other encoding. Perhaps give the https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet library a try, and see what it thinks the encoding is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to parse a csv file that uses `excel` dialect in Python 3:

```
with open('/file.csv', newline='', encoding=correct_encoding) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
```

Your issue might be the incorrect input character encoding:

```
>>> print(u'Côte d’Ivoire'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252'))
CÃ´te dâ€™Ivoire
```

The example shows what happens if utf-8 data is decoded as cp1252.

Comment: When I replace 'cp1252' with 'utf-8' in the open call I get the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x99 in position 3688: invalid start byte` once it reaches the first row with special characters. How do you suggest getting around that?

Comment: the point is that your issue has nothing to do with csv. Your file may be corrupted (e.g., no single character encoding that decodes it exists). Try to open the file in a browser and see what encoding it selects.